# Proof that a sequence has a convergent subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

I have a bounded sequence $a(n)$. We consider the set of all the values of $a(n)$ and let $M$ be the supremum of this set (without being one of its elements). Now we want to show that there is a subsequence of $a(n)$ that converges to $M$.
It would be trivial if we could show that $a(n)$ has a monotonic increasing subsequence but this isn't always the case... My main problem here is that I think that the fast I need to prove isn't actually right...

Can you help me on this one? Thank you!

Comment: Every sequence in $\mathbb R$ has a monotone subsequence. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano-Weierstrass_theorem.

Comment: You can't prove that $a(n)$ contains a subsequence that converges to $M$, because it's not true in general. Do you mean $M = \lim \sup a(n)$?

Comment: @TonyK You missed the assumption that the supremum does not appear in the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

To get your subsequence, pick $a_{n_1}>M-1$. Later on, if you have $n_1,\ldots,n_k$, pick $n_{k+1}>n_k$ with $a_{n_{k+1}}>M-1/(k+1)$. This is possible because $M\notin\{a_1,\ldots,a_{n_k}\}$, so $M=\sup\{a_j:j>n_k\}$.

You can even require $a_{n_{k+1}}>a_{n_k}$, but this is not important for convergence.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing... You pick the first term of the subsequence, that I understand. But then, what are you aiming to do exactly? Can you give more details?

Comment: I am picking a subsequence converging to $M$. The inequality $a_{n_{k+1}}>M-1/(k+1)$ ensures that. The important thing to note is that because $M$ (the supremum!) is not in the sequence, it is also the supremum of any tail of the sequence. For there will always be a gap between the largest member of any finite section of the sequence and $M$.